# Regarding pymatbridge

Tags: python, matlab, sockets, ubuntu

I'm learning on how to execute Matlab code(.m file) from python script. So I have installed pymatbridge but I was unable to make it successfully. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Matlab version 2013 and python 2.7.3.

I have followed the link http://arokem.github.io/python-matlab-bridge/
and pasted the commands below but got an error saying unexpected keyword argument 'host'.

> > > from pymatbridge import Matlab
> > >       mlab=Matlab()
> > >       **mlab=Matlab(matlab='/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab', host='192.168.0.1',port=5151)**
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'host'

**So I have changed the commands as,**

> > > **mlab=Matlab(matlab='/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab')**
> > >       mlab.start()
> > >       Starting MATLAB on ZMQ socket ipc:///tmp/pymatbridge 
> > >       Send 'exit' command to kill the server
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymatbridge/pymatbridge.py", line 135, in start
> > >           if (self.is_connected()):
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymatbridge/pymatbridge.py", line 168, in is_connected
> > >           resp = self.socket.recv_string(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
> > >         File "socket.pyx", line 456, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.**getattr** (zmq/core/socket.c:4576)
> > >       AttributeError: Socket has no such option: RECV_STRING
> > >
> > > ```
> > >                         < M A T L A B (R) >
> > >               Copyright 1984-2013 The MathWorks, Inc.
> > >                 R2013a (8.1.0.604) 64-bit (glnxa64)
> > >                          February 15, 2013
> > > ```
> > >
> > > To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
> > >       For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
> > >       Invalid MEX-file
> > >       '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymatbridge/matlab/messenger.mexa64':
> > >       libzmq.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> > >       Error in matlabserver (line 7)
> > >       messenger('init', socket_address);

Kindly help me out as to how to solve this, since I'm new to programming and not comfortable with ubuntu as well.

Regards,
Gokul.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the documentation on http://arokem.github.io/python-matlab-bridge/ is out of date with the master branch on the repository and relates to the release version 0.2. The documentation here: https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge is the one that is relevant to the current development version.

As for your problem, I think that you need to get libzmq on your machine. On ubuntu that is done by executing the following at your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. The error about the Invalid Mex-file and matlab server is solved. But the first errors was not solved <br/> 
File "", line 1, in
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymatbridge/pymatbridge.py", line 135, in start
if (self.is_connected()):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymatbridge/pymatbridge.py", line 168, in is_connected
resp = self.socket.recv_string(flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
File "socket.pyx", line 456, in zmq.core.socket.Socket.getattr (zmq/core/socket.c:4576)
AttributeError: Socket has no such option: RECV_STRING